How to merge arrays within JSON object
Given a JSON object
{
"foo":["barfoo"],
"bar":["foobar"]
}

I would like to merge both arrays, i.e. output:
barfoo
foobar

Obviously I can list either array using, e.g. jq -r .foo[] but I'm not sure how to go about merging both.
The array names (foo / bar) are constants, they do not change.

I'm not sure why that output requires you to merge anything. jq -r '.[][]' doesn't do any merging, it just prints one after the other, but it seems to be what you want nonetheless. Of course, you could also run jq -r '.foo[], .bar[]'; again, there's no merging -- it's not creating a single item with both foo content and bar content and writing that one item; rather, it's first outputting each item from foo separately, then outputting each item from bar separately.

To get all the second-level items, iterate two levels deep:
jq -r '.[][]'

To get all the leaf-level items, descend recursively, and filter for scalars:
jq -r '..|scalars'


If your JSON is saved as a file named "file.json", you can get the output in the specified format using this command:
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .value[]' file.json

To explain how this works:

to_entries[] converts the JSON object into an array of key-value pairs
.value[] iterates over each value array and prints each element on a new line
-r formats the output as raw text

